# How to add text below the images in NiceTabular environment

Tags: pdftex, captions, tcolorbox, ieeetran, nicematrix

I would like to ask how to place some text below the images generated by this figure:

```
\documentclass[journal,twocolumn,10pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<
\usepackage[center]{caption} % centering the caption


\begin{document}    

\newlength{\FrameHeight}
\setlength{\FrameHeight}{0.165\textwidth} % to control the figure Frame width and height

\begin{figure*}

\begin{NiceTabular}{rl}[cell-space-limits=1.2pt] % add space between rows 
        
\Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-6-FRAMES-crop.pdf}}&
\Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-6-ALL.pdf}}
    \\ 
\Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-3-FRAMES-crop.pdf}}&
\Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-3-ALL.pdf}}
    \\
\Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-26-FRAMES-crop.pdf}}&
\Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-26-ALL.pdf}}
    \\
\Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-16-FRAMES-crop.pdf}}&
\Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-16-ALL.pdf}}
    \\
    
\end{NiceTabular}

\caption{Combinations examples from session S4}\label{SESION4}
\end{figure*}   
    
\end{document}
```

The .PDF images are in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5id0v3yrzi5ifeb/AACcWhg1s5jwVanVAr6faEEKa?dl=0).

I would like to create a figure like the following:

[image]

where `"Combination: LH-LH-LH-RH...` is below images.

Comment: Your link to images probably be dead after while. Yo should prepare MWE with some example images (for example from `mwe or `graphicx` package, which are available to any one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\Block` command allows you to use `\\` inside, so adding a line of text is straightforward.

**First page**

In the last row, the figure on the right fills the table cell, so `\Block[c]{}{...` will center the figure and the line of text.

In the other three rows, the simplest solution is to add blank space at the end of the text line, `\hspace {..}`, calculated by eye.

[image: z1]

**Second page**

On the second page a more exact solution. The image and the line of text are encapsulated in a `parbox` and centered on each other.

The width of each parbox was calculated taking into account the relationship between the heights of the individual frames and the widths of the number of frames for each case (two, four and six).

It was added a small gap between the figure and the line of text.

[image: z5]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[journal,twocolumn,10pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<
\usepackage[center]{caption} % centering the caption    

\begin{document}    
    
    \newlength{\FrameHeight}
    \setlength{\FrameHeight}{0.165\textwidth} % to control the figures *FRAMES width and height 
    
        \begin{figure*}
        
        \begin{NiceTabular}{rl}[cell-space-limits=1.2pt] % add space between rows 
            
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-6-FRAMES-crop.pdf} \\ 
                Combination: LH-LH\hspace*{0.08\FrameHeight}}&
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-6-ALL.pdf}}
            \\ 
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-3-FRAMES-crop.pdf}\\
                Combination: LH-LH-LH-RH\hspace*{0.58\FrameHeight}}&
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-3-ALL.pdf}}
            \\
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-26-FRAMES-crop.pdf}\\
                Combination: LH-LH-LH-RH\hspace*{0.58\FrameHeight}}&
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-26-ALL.pdf}}
            \\
            \Block[c]{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-16-FRAMES-crop.pdf}\\
                Combination: LH-LH-LH-RH-LH-RH}&
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-16-ALL.pdf}}
            \\
            
        \end{NiceTabular}
        
        \caption{Combinations examples from session S4}\label{SESION4}
    \end{figure*}   
    
    
\begin{figure*}
        
        \begin{NiceTabular}{rl}[cell-space-limits=1.2pt] % add space between rows 
                                            
            \Block{}{%
            \parbox{1.32\FrameHeight}{\centering
                    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-6-FRAMES-crop.pdf} \\ \smallskip
                 Combination: LH-LH}} &
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-6-ALL.pdf}}
            \\ 
            \Block{}{%
                \parbox{2.66\FrameHeight}{\centering
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-3-FRAMES-crop.pdf}\\ \smallskip
                 Combination: LH-LH-LH-RH}}&
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-3-ALL.pdf}}
            \\
            \Block{}{%
                    \parbox{2.66\FrameHeight}{\centering
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-26-FRAMES-crop.pdf}\\ \smallskip
                 Combination: LH-LH-LH-RH}}&
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-26-ALL.pdf}}
            \\
            \Block{}{%
                \parbox{4.0\FrameHeight}{\centering
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-16-FRAMES-crop.pdf}\\ \smallskip
                Combination: LH-LH-LH-RH-LH-RH}}&
            \Block{}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=1.85\FrameHeight]{_kkk/javier-sesion-14-SEC-16-ALL.pdf}}
            \\              
            
        \end{NiceTabular}
        
        \caption{Combinations examples from session S4}\label{SESION4}
    \end{figure*}       

\end{document}
```